# Error in Calculated Column (using Today) in DataSheet View - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2013

I have calulated column which display's the value based on the difference between today and requested date field.

=Today-[Requested Date]

This is working fine in Sharepoint Standard View. But the same is not working with the datasheet view . The calculated column is showing as below

=#NAME?-[Requested Date].

Due to this i am not able to save the data. Can anyone please let me know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which SharePoint version are you using?

I tried the same scenario using SharePoint 2013 and was able to add the values in both standard and datasheet views. I am assuming you might have used the same steps.

- Create 2 new columns named **RequestedDate**(DateTime) and
  **Today**(Single line of text).
- Add a new column of type calculated field with formula
  **=Today-[Requested Date]**.
- Now **delete** the Today column.
- Try entering the data in both the views.

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2010. Yes same steps that you have mentioned.

Comment: I tried using SharePoint 2010 in IE7,IE8 and IE9. In datasheet view, before adding the value i get =#NAME in the calc field column. But, as soon as I enter the RequestedDate the value show up.

Comment: Please verify creating a new list or using a different browser or even from a different machine. Meanwhile I shall also try!

Comment: Thanks Neal  .I tried creating a new list . This is working .

Comment: Great! There might have been some problem with the list I suppose!

Comment: I tried the trick which you have mentioned above. But it works while I enter the data. When I open the list for the next day or some other day's after, the Calculated column is not taking the current day's value, do the data remains same in the calculated column. what should i need to do in case it needs to take current date's value and calculate the formula and changes the value daily?

Answer (score 0):

First I have used today() function to calculate difference between 2 days except working days. The list is not automatically updating. If we change the Start_Date, then it calculates and gives the value. Can you suggest me why this happens?

You have mentioned in your post that there is some tricks in using today() function. I have created separate Today_Date column in my list. And Used the same column name in finding difference between 2 days. Here also the same problem exists.

The formula I used is,

```
=IF(AND((WEEKDAY([Today Date],2))<(WEEKDAY([Release Date],2)),((WEEKDAY([Release Date],2))-(WEEKDAY([Today Date],2)))>1),(((DATEDIF([Release Date],[Today Date],"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Release Date],[Today Date],"D")+1)/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF([Release Date],[Today Date],"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Release Date],[Today Date],"D")+1)/7,1)*2)))
```

Please tell me how to make the difference between 2 date values update automatically every time I open the list.

Then I tried the trick which you have mentioned above. But it works while I enter the data. When I open the list for the next day or some other day's after the Calculated column is not taking the current day's value, do the data remains same. what should I need to do in case it needs to take current date's value and calculate the formula?

Comment: Dear User, There no function in Sharepoint like Today() . As far as I know there is trick available . You need to create a column with name "Today" it can of type Single line of text. Then in the calculated field use the formula as requeried eg: Today-[Requested Date]. Once you have finished entering all the calulated field with Today . Delete the today column . Now enter the data it should work. If still not solving your problem , post it as a new question

Comment: yeah.. it has worked while entering the data. But when I open the list on the other day, for example 3 days after. it is not recalculating by taking current date's value. Everything remains the same..

Comment: Ya Once the Data is saved it will not recalculate . You need to edit and save it it again .

Comment: Is there any other way to do it automatically. How about creating a workflow which automatically triggers to modify today's date at a particular timing say at non-office timings? so that it will be ready by next day nah?